# Sencha touch 2 ProgressBar.js file not found

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

```
 var versionFlag;
 Ext.define('Cranedge.controller.LoginPage', {
 extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
 xtype: 'MainController',
 requires: [
   'Ext.ProgressBar'
 ],
 config : {
   refs:{
 }
 }
control :{
  loginButton:{
    tap:'getData'
  }
}
},
 getData:function(){
  var SyncDataProgressBar = Ext.create('Ext.ProgressBar', {
         renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
         width: 300
  });

  SyncDataProgressBar.wait({
    interval: 60000, //bar will move fast!
    duration: 900000,
    increment: 15,
    text: 'Syncying data...',
    scope: this,
  });

  //Mycode

     SyncDataProgressBar.hide();
 });
```

while executing this code in browser follwing error show in console

Uncaught Error: [Ext.Loader] Failed loading 'touch/src/ProgressBar.js', please verify that the file exists

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the following element:

```
requires: [
   'Ext.ProgressBar'
 ],
```

This element is looking for a ProgressBar element that cannot found because **Ext.ProgressBar** doesn't exist to Sencha Touch 2.x as you can see on the following documentation:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/

Best Regards,

Comment: But there is no Ext.ProgessBar in Sencha. Is it a custom component what you want to use?

Comment: ProgressBar exists on ExtJS: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.ProgressBar The problem is that you need to create or initialize a **Ext.ProgressBar** element.

Comment: As martin comments, doesn't exist **Ext.ProgressBar** on Sencha Touch 2 http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/